# How to wait till file get downloaded completely. C#

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I'm downloading one file using WebClient in one of the method.

```
public static void DownloadServicePackage()
{
    FilePath = @"C:\Users\userName\AppData\TestExe.zip".Replace("userName", userName);
    string extractPath = @"C:\Users\userName\AppData".Replace("userName", userName);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFile("https://stg.test.com/downloadScript/TestExe.zip", FilePath);
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(FilePath, extractPath);
}

public MainWindow()
{ 
    DownloadServicePackage();
    DownloadFile();
}
```

I need to wait in this method until zip file gets downloaded completely. So that I can extract further.
Any suggestions? How can I achieve this as I don't want to proceed till file get downloaded. Also file size can differ from time to time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`DownloadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=net-6.0) already blocks until the file is downloaded. What is the actual problem you're having?

Comment: @DStanley The file size is around 35MB, so it is taking time to download. Meanwhile further code is running. The requirement is like to get downloaded that file completely and then run further code.

Comment: What "further code"? We can't see it in your question yet and therefore cannot comment.

Comment: From the documentation: "The DownloadFile method downloads to a local file data from the URI specified by in the address parameter. ***This method blocks while downloading the resource.*** "

Comment: Again, what is the actual problem? Is the "further code" trying to use that file and getting some error? If so, what error is that?

Comment: So what is the error? `DownloadFile` is already synchronous, so are you getting a timeout due to file size? Do you get an error that the file is in use? Something else?  You're asking how to wait until the file is downloaded, but `DownloadFile` _should already do that_. If it's not, then we need more information.